# How to scrape a span with a certain title in scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to use Scrapy with the CSS path to get the text in the fields of a number of *span*  items. The CSS look like this:

```
<div class="announcement">
    <span title="Name">Homer Simpson</span>
    <span title="Date">2018-09-19</span>
    <span title="Type">House</span>
</div>
```

I have tried with this:

```
response.css("div.announcement span::attr(title)").extract()
# ['Name', 'Date', 'Type']

response.css("div.announcement span::text").extract()
# ['Homer Simpson', '2018-09-19', 'House']
```

But that only results in a repeated list of the *span* titles, or I get all of them, but I just want one at the time. What I would like to have is something like:

```
response.css("div.announcement <SomeMagicHere>('Name')").extract()
# ['Homer Simpson']
```

**How can I get a list of only the content of each of the *title* items, separately?**

Comment: So what is your desired output?

Comment: @andersson I have edited the question to show what I want.

Comment: Just a list with only first element or each element in a list, like  `[['Name'], ['Date'], ['Type']]`?

Comment: Basically, yes. The problem is that sometimes one of the *title*'s (as in my example above) doesn't exists, or the field is empty. So I think I need to actually check or specify the *title text* (i.e. "Name"). Which is why I can't just hope that `[0]` would give me what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "contains" attribute:

```
response.css("div.announcement span[title*='Name']::text").extract()
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!